# get value outside foreach php and make custom array

Tags: php, arrays, parsing

how to get value outside foreach php, and make to custom array

```
$cookie = '__Secure1=AmPeJJXmCLtDSJ5pn;__Secure2=h7XmRQ.;__Secure3=AJi4QfEYBhuC;';
$explode = explode(";", $cookie);
foreach($explode as $data){
    $data = explode("=",$data);
    $name = $data[0];
    $value = $data[1];
}
$cookie_array =  array(
        'name' => $name,
        'value' => $value
    );
print_r($cookie_array);
```

Comment: Which value do you want, there are 3 which is why you are looping ??

Comment: Maybe you want to do that inside the loop

Comment: @SwatantraKumar Why are you trying to add errors to the question

Comment: how to make output `['name' => '__Secure1', 'value'=>'AmPeJJXmCLtDSJ5pn','name' => '__Secure2', 'value'=>'h7XmRQ','name' => '__Secure3', 'value'=>'AJi4QfEYBhuC']`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should simply initialize your $cookie_array before you do your foreach, and then push data into that array in the foreach, like this:

```
$cookie_array = [];

foreach($explode as $data){
    $data = explode("=",$data);

    $cookie_array[] = [
        'name' => $data[0],
        'value' => $data[1]
    ];
}

print_r($cookie_array);
```

Comment: thanks sir I've tried it first, but I'm confused about combining the output from the array, example :


`['name' => '__Secure1', 'value'=>'AmPeJJXmCLtDSJ5pn','name' => '__Secure2', 'value'=>'h7XmRQ','name' => '__Secure3', 'value'=>'AJi4QfEYBhuC']`

Comment: @Rizky I'm not quite sure what you mean by this? Do you want an array where the values are not nested arrays? It is not possible to have values with the same keys, as the example you are posting here.